# Psql: Not a directory

Tags: linux, terminal, postgresql

I found my psql folder typing :

```
$ which psql
/usr/bin/psql
```

But when I Tried get in I got this:

where I am:

```
root@localhost:/usr/bin#
$ cd psql
-bash: cd: psql: Not a directory
```

I can see the folder is there but i can't access, I am using Root User.

Comment: please, specify exactly what you are looking for : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact it's not a directory, it is a symlink:

```
# ls -la psql 
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 28 Jul 23 14:38 psql -> /etc/alternatives/pgsql-psql
```

that point to an other symlink:

```
ls -la  /etc/alternatives/pgsql-psql
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 23 Jul 23 14:38 /etc/alternatives/pgsql-psql -> /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql
```

that in the end, it is an executable file

```
# ls -la /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 425192 Jun 11 14:51 /usr/pgsql-9.1/bin/psql
```

Exactly what you are looking for? I just guess that you are looking for postgres home folder, you can find it as follow:

```
# become the user postgres
su postgres
# change directory to the postgres home folder
cd ~
```

In my case, this folder is located in `/var/lib/pgsql` as you can see:

```
bash-4.1$ pwd
/var/lib/pgsql
```

Comment: yes it is :), very nice explanation about symlink, I was looking for my database backup  and someone told me will be there  and I found : /var/lib/postgresql#